# Are simultaneous reads of an array in swift thread-safe?

Tags: arrays, swift, multithreading, locking

In my app, I want several threads to simultaneously read data from a 2-d array `[[Item]]`, without writing/modifying anything in the process.

I am wondering if it is OK to forego locks? Or, it is thread-safe to read from a swift array?

For a simple "block of memory" type of array, this is not worth worrying about. But I am not sure swift's implementation of `Array` involves any other data structures that may get corrupted in simutaneous access?